# What ggplot function allows adding secondary aesthetics without affecting original lims/labels/panel of original plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I came across a seemingly niche function in ggplot that allows adding a new geom to a plot, without affecting the setup of the original plot in terms of lims/panel/etc. Using said function would simply clip the new geom at the boundaries of the plot without removing out-of-bound data (i.e. lines are allowed to continue to the edge of the plot and then just get clipped).

After a lot of search (google and browsing history), I cannot find that function.

Assume we need a plot with points and errorbars, where the errorbars are clipped by the panel boundaries. The setup would look something like the following; let's name the missing function `gg_missfn`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(...)) +
    geom_point() +

    # the missing function below
    gg_missfn(df2, aes(...), geom = 'errorbar')
```

Anyone have any idea of what the function is? I know this is possible through `coord_cartesian` , but the function serves a more succinct approach to achieving the same goal.

Comment: Do you mean `override.aes`?

Comment: I need to do some more reading on `override.aes`, but I'm not sure that's the one. It is a great suggestion as a tool for me to keep an eye out for though! I'm not sure if the option I'm looking for did have an effect on legend, but it's more about plotting within an original panel with appropriate clipping. I came across it two weeks ago buried in some documentation/website and can't recall it, even though I experimented a bit with it.